# How to create Amazon wishlist link?

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-product-api

I can see some people can create a Amazon wishlist included their item and their address.Some link or code like this :

```
https://www.amazon.com/gp/item-dispatch/ref=cm_wl_addtocart_v_nS?session-id=133-2297636-4319425&registryID.1=86NIQUDDNE6T&offeringID.1=zN8ppykunCEHZK%252Fkig4t15ol%252BDnq%252Fg4squfXbV9E1bCoVkuEz4DT88jRyZWBZ1uoM38BX29jtWfMY2Y5h1zyI%252BOMXRnnJrsBVAfrLR8EWZEkCnw%252BaG6F9A%253D%253D&submit.addToCart=1&registryItemID.1=IQYZEO1CMKGDN&quantity.1=2&ie=UTF8
```

Or like this

```
<form action="https://www.amazon.com/gp/item-dispatch/ref=cm_wl_addtocart_v_nS" target="_blank" method="GET">
 <input type="hidden" value="134-9110026-5779330" name="session-id">
 <input type="hidden" value="U56EZYX00V8S" name="registryID.1">
 <input type="hidden" value="zrwbNhkcwW3R8HBawRjamDLqZLRtQ51xS+SaRF28Y55gWkqPpEvvHftNdiHymVEuDoLIkIOa362eCz1JulIFxgK1MP/F63o6sma3wzlY5FaXMOQmjffg0Hl8rRv7eYkUoN0nKy/+mKHoML2JMppdQ872HvhzHyGp" name="offeringID.1">
 <input type="hidden" value="1" name="submit.addToCart">
 <input type="hidden" value="IYC2M8M6HFVRY" name="registryItemID.1">
 <input type="hidden" value="1" name="quantity.1">
 <input type="hidden" value="UTF8" name="ie">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Purchase Order</button>
</form>
```

When i input that link, Amazon will show the item and the address in shipping page.

My question is how can i create a lin like that.Have any online tool or code can do that.

Thank you !

Comment: is your question on how to get your amazon referal link or to implement the same in ur website?

Comment: I want to send a link like that to my friend that they can completed purchased item for me.

Comment: That link contain item and my address.But i don't know how to create a link like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this from your amazon account itself.

a. Add the item to your amazon wishlist.

b. click on  list settings (upper left top  link in your wishlist page)

c. click view details of the product you want

d. associate a delivery address with the product

e. you might also want to check the 'third party shipping agreement' checkbox

f. go back to wishlist page

h. click on share link and copy the link

g. send it to your friends

I think you should create a new wishlist for every  single product you want to share. I don't think there is an upper limit on the number of wishlists that you can create. Don't know if there is a workaround for single product otherwise.

Comment: Hi ! i need separate address on each product.I want to do that link because i am a dropshipping service.I should give that link for people who can order product for me.